# ¿Cómo puedo calcular cuantos "ceros" consecutivos hay rodeados de "unos"?

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer esto:

> **Dado un entero positivo N, devuelve la longitud de la secuencia máxima de "ceros" consecutivos que está rodeados de "unos"**

Ejemplos:

- El número 9 tiene una representación binaria 1001 y contiene una secuencia de ceros longitud 2. Devuelve 2.
- El número 529 tiene una representación binaria 1000010001 y contiene dos secuencias de ceros: uno de longitud 4 y otro de longitud 3. Devuelve 4.
- El número 20 tiene representación binaria de 10100 y contiene una secuencia de ceros de longitud 1. Devuelve 1.
- El número 15 tiene una representación binaria 1111 y no tiene secuencia de ceros. Devuelve 0.

Os enseño el código que tengo, y no se como continuar, he conseguido convertir el numero en vinario y lo he pasado a `String`.

```
public class Ejercicio2 {


  public static void main(String[] args) {

      int numero ;
      Scanner sc;
      String binarioString;
      String[] binarioDividido;

      sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("introduce un numero:");
      numero = sc.nextInt();
      binarioString = Ejercicio2.obtenerBinario(numero);
      sc.close();       
      binarioDividido = binarioString.split("1");

  }


  public static String obtenerBinario(int numero) {
      String numeroBinario = "";
      List<String> binario = new ArrayList<String>();
      int resto;

      for (int i = numero; numero >= 2;) {
          resto = numero%2;
          numero = numero/2;
          binario.add(0, Integer.toString(resto));
          i = numero;
      }

      if(numero == 2) {     
      numero = numero/2;        
      }     
      binario.add(0, Integer.toString(numero));

      for(int i = 0; i< binario.size(); i++) {
          numeroBinario += binario.get(i);
      }
      return numeroBinario;             
  }

}
```

Comment: Seria correcto que muestres un ejemplo de entrada y lo que debería devolver para entender más rápido lo que pedís.

Comment: pot ejemplo tu introduces 150, lo combiertes a binario, y obtienes 10010110, el resultado que tienes que obtener es 2 por que entre el primer 1 y el segundo hay una longitud de 2 ceros, aun asi pongo en la pregunta el ejemplo

Comment: Te dejo un link: https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler donde podes probar tu código java online

Answer (score 2):

En realidad ya hiciste lo mas dificil, que es transformar el numero a binario.. lo que resta, es solo contar.

Y para contar, es como si contaras en papel, o en cualquier otro lado, de a uno...

No hay soluciones magicas.

Entonces, lo que tenes que hacer es recorrer esa cadena, ir contando ceros, y cuando encontras un uno, fijarte si esa fue la cadena mas larga de ceros que encontraste. Como los del final no te interesan se van a ir solos.

En detalle, seria algo asi:

Definimos las variables que necesitamos, x vendria de antes, pero maxceros se usa para saber la cadena mas larga de ceros y cuentaactual para saber cuantos ceros vamos contando

```
String x="1000010001";
int maxceros = 0;
int cuentaactual = 0;
```

Entonces, vamos a interar sobre nuestra cadena, en este caso x

```
for(int i = 0; i < x.length();i++) {
```

Lo primemor que hacemos al entrar, es comparar si es un cero. Si esta posicion es un cero, entonces le sumamos 1 a la cuenta que tenemos de cero (cuentaactual)

```
    if (x.substring(i,i+1).equals("0")) {
        cuentaactual+=1;
```

Si no es un cero, entonces nos fijamos si la cuentaactual es mayor que la cadena de ceros maximo que teniamos antes (maxceros). Si es mayor, cambiamos el maximo a este.. si no es mayor, no hacemos nada.

```
    } else {
        if (cuentaactual > maxceros) {
            maxceros = cuentaactual;
        }
```

Ahora, siempre que encontremos un 1, reiniciamos la cuenta de ceros.

```
        cuentaactual = 0;
    }
```

Al terminar el for, solo imprimimos la longitud maxima de ceros que encontramos.

```
}
System.out.println("maximo: " + maxceros);
```

Answer (score 1):

Te comento una lógica que podes implementar, cortar el string que formaste con el binario por el split "1" , luego recorres ese array generado y te quedas con el subarreglo con mayor longitud.

Probá este ejemplo:

```html
public class Ejercicio2 {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String binario = "100010000100000000100000100001000000000000000000000";
    String[] array = binario.split("1");
    int max_cantidad_ceros = 0, aux=0; // aux vamos guardando las cantidades de 0
    
    for (int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
        aux = array[i].length();
        if (aux > max_cantidad_ceros) 
            max_cantidad_ceros = aux; 
    }
    
    System.out.println("Máxima cantidad de ceros : "+ max_cantidad_ceros);


}

}
```

Comment: gracias, pero esta opcion no me sirve, pues solo hay qe contar los "0" que estan entre "1", con esta opcion tambien contaria con los ceros del final.

Comment: Eso no sería un problema, simplemente elimina el ultimo sub array del arreglo generado }:D

Comment: Fijate que ahí te modifique el ejemplo contemplando tu comentario. Espero te sirva }:D

Answer (score 1):

Esta respuesta es muy parecida a las que ya te dieron: contar los grupos consecutivos de 0 y "recordar" el grupo con el mayor número, sin embargo, lo distinto en este caso, es evitar la construcción de la representación binaria. La idea es trabajar directamente con el número recibido y usar los [Bitwise y Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html). El código es muy simple y común, así que simplemente voy a usar [este](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/length-of-longest-consecutive-zeroes-in-the-binary-representation-of-a-number/), los comentarios agregados son míos:

```
static int maxZeros(int N) 
{ 
    int maxm = -1; 
    int cnt = 0; 

    while (N != 0) { 
        // "Bitwise And" en (N & 1) comparamos por ejemplo:
        // 1000010001 (529)
        // 0000000001 (1)
        // El and lógico en este caso será 1. Luego iremos haciendo un "shift" del número
        // (N >>= 1) es decir con cada vuelta del ciclo iremos quitando un bit al número a derecha.
        if ((N & 1) == 0 ) { 
            cnt++; 
            N >>= 1; 
            maxm = Math.max(maxm, cnt); 
        } 
        else { 

            maxm = Math.max(maxm, cnt); 
            cnt = 0; 
            N >>= 1; 
        } 
    } 
    return maxm; 
}
```